# How to retrieve specific date data from the table in kusto query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I need to retrieve the specific date data from the table
Can any one help me out this..

Sample data:

| Timestamp | message |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-09-12 | king |
| 2010-09-12 | queen |
| 2010-09-13 | raju |
| 2010-09-13 | Rani |
| 2010-09-14 | Ramu |
| 2010-09-12 | somu |

Expecting results:

| Timestamp | message |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-09-12 | king |
| 2010-09-12 | queen |
| 2010-09-12 | somu |

Only 2010-09-12 date results required.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all datetime values are at the start of the day then you can use a simple equality.

```
datatable(Timestamp:datetime, message:string)
[
    datetime("2010-09-12") ,"king"
   ,datetime("2010-09-12") ,"queen"
   ,datetime("2010-09-13") ,"raju"
   ,datetime("2010-09-13") ,"Rani"
   ,datetime("2010-09-14") ,"Ramu"
   ,datetime("2010-09-12") ,"somu"
]
| where Timestamp == datetime("2010-09-12")
```

If all datetime values are at the start of the day then you can use a simple equality.

| Timestamp | message |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-09-12T00:00:00Z | king |
| 2010-09-12T00:00:00Z | queen |
| 2010-09-12T00:00:00Z | somu |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUjZDM3NTiksTcAquUxJLUEiBPRwEoUpyYnmpVXFKUmZeuycsVzculAAQwFRpKRgaGBroGlrqGRkqaCjpK2UBlSmA1OjjVFJampubhVmQMVlSUmFVKSE1QYl4mbjUmUDW5eMyBOKg4H6wmlperRqE8I7UoVQEeFgq2tjg8CwBJYargOQEAAA==)

If datetime values have timestamp parts, you'll need to check a range of dates.

```
datatable(Timestamp:datetime, message:string)
[
    datetime("2010-09-12 00:00:00") ,"king"
   ,datetime("2010-09-12 12:34:56") ,"queen"
   ,datetime("2010-09-13 00:00:00") ,"raju"
   ,datetime("2010-09-13 15:23:02") ,"Rani"
   ,datetime("2010-09-14 11:11:11") ,"Ramu"
   ,datetime("2010-09-12 02:03:04") ,"somu"
]
| where Timestamp >= datetime("2010-09-12") and Timestamp < datetime("2010-09-13")
```

| Timestamp | message |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-09-12T00:00:00Z | king |
| 2010-09-12T02:03:04Z | somu |
| 2010-09-12T12:34:56Z | queen |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA33QzQrCMAwH8Ptg7xB62mCDfkzBoD6EeBMPlYU5dVW3Di8+vKGoKGxrcmn59Q9JaT3X4ULJtm6o87a5YWk9eb5lwC+drQg739auSuNoF0fA5yMSoaWSuVzkSoOUGFqkkIkzexFwNoiVRlPgbB7wvSdy49r8R7f21E9hNUNtUOqAN9bV47gApTD0GzcTyTyhRsnJRcDdNeB9HD3hcaSW4LtBWK8GV8T/rCt/3HKIGZG+AMsG97GWAQAA)

Comment: @ David דודו Markovitz

Table
| where message has "king"
| where timestamp == datetime("2010-09-12")

I'm getting "No results found from the specified time range"

Comment: Have you tried the 2nd option?

Comment: yes, but i need only specific day data only, i don't want b/w 2 days data

Comment: The 2nd query returns a single day. You can see it in the demo.